# PHP cURL Json Post - doing something wrong

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm new to php and I'm trying to create a simple example for calling our company api.  I got NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 to work last night (yay) but I cannot seem to get the following code to show me anything.  I can run it in the debugger. I can step through it.  I even get to the end without errors, but the curl_exec returns just 0.  I have added the CURLOPT_PROXYPORT so that I can get fiddler to see the traffic, but fiddler sees nothing.  I am also trying to run this as a php command line (if that has any bearing).

I know I'm doing something stupid... but that's the problem with stupid.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://target.boomerang.com/api/JobCreate';
$authToken = 'phptest';
$data = array(
    "emailHTML" => "Howdy",
    "jobKind" => "email",
    "senderEmail" => "bob@boomerang.com",
    "subject" => "My howdy email"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'auth_token: ' . $authToken,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Expect:'
);
$ch = curl_init();
$args = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => "localhost:8888"
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $args);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$res_data = json_decode($res, true);
print($res_data);
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does [curl_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) call (placed right after curl_exec()) return?

Comment: I'll check the curl_error() now.  Thanks!BTW, if you want to test, the temporary auth_token I have included should work.

Comment: Oooh!  That helped!  "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was caused by SSL certificate mismatch? I suppose it can be solved by adding this...

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
```

...into $args array.

Comment: That did it!  Actually I added just CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false according to this article:  http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/ - thanks for your help!